# Не работает вторая карта yandex

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет,я тут первый раз
верстаю макет, на двух разных страницах есть карта яндекс. Но вторая карта не загружается, если удалить код из js первой карты, то вторая подгружается
что не так?

```js
var myMap1;
var myMap2;
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    myMap1 = new ymaps.Map("map1", {
  center: [55.81254956891398,37.8328265],
  zoom: 17,
  controls: []
 });

    myMap2 = new ymaps.Map("map2", {
  center: [59.92979687173394,30.37630978241727],
  zoom: 15,
  controls: ['zoomControl']
 });
  var myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([59.92979956418111,30.37499549999999], { 
   hintContent: 'Экоковрики',
   balloonContent: 'Санкт Петербург, пр. Бакунина 5,<br> офис 512.<br>Тел: +7 495 268 07 31'
  },
  {
   preset: 'islands#redIcon'
  });
 
  myMap2.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);

    
};
```

```html
первая страница

<section class="contacts">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="map1" style="width: 100%; height: 460px">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 contacts-xs">
      <div class="contacts-block">
       <h2>Контакты</h2>
       <a class="phone" href="tel:84952680731">+7 495 268-07-31</a>
       <p class="desc">звонок по России бесплатный</p>
       <a class="mail" href="mailto:info@kovrikeva.ru">E-mail: info@kovrikeva.ru</a>
       <p class="time">Пн-Сб 9:00-18:30</p>
       <p class="address">г. Москва, Щелковское шоссе д.100</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
</section>

вторая страница

<section class="contacts-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contacts-content">
            <h2>Контакты</h2>
            <div class="address-block">
                <p class="country">Россия</p>
                <p class="address"><span>Санкт Петербург,</span>пр. Бакунина 5, офис 512.</p>
                <a class="phone" href="tel:84952680731">Тел: +7 495 268 07 31</a>
            </div>
            <div class="map-block">
                <div id="map2" style="width: 700px; height: 354px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="requisites-block">
                <h3>Реквизиты компании</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Код надо уставлять текстом

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: А вы пробовали для начала в консоль посмотреть на предмет ошибок?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Comment: Вангую, что на второй странице нет div с id=map1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагаю, что причина ошибки - неверно заданные размеры блоков для отображения карт.

```js
var myMap1;
var myMap2;
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  if (document.getElementById('map1')) {
      myMap1 = new ymaps.Map("map1", {
        center: [55.81254956891398, 37.8328265],
        zoom: 17,
        controls: []
      });
    }

    if (document.getElementById('map2')) {
        myMap2 = new ymaps.Map("map2", {
          center: [59.92979687173394, 30.37630978241727],
          zoom: 15,
          controls: ['zoomControl']
        });
        var myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([59.92979956418111, 30.37499549999999], {
          hintContent: 'Экоковрики',
          balloonContent: 'Санкт Петербург, пр. Бакунина 5,<br> офис 512.<br>Тел: +7 495 268 07 31'
        }, {
          preset: 'islands#redIcon'
        });
      }

      myMap2.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);


    };
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map1,
#map2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.map-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rm;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map1"></div>
</div>
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: когда удаляю переменную myMap1 - то вторая карта работает

Comment: <div id="map1" style="width: 100%; height: 460px">
<div class="map-block">
     <div id="map2" style="width: 700px; height: 354px"></div>
</div>

Comment: Попробуйте добавить проверку существования div для отображения карты, как советует @AlexeyTen. Пример проверки добавил в код примера

Comment: с вашей проверкой(копировал только js код без html) - заработали две карты

Comment: Отлично ) Не стесняйтесь отмечать правильные ответы, как правильные, а полезные, как полезные